# Jupyter Notebook 内で環境変数を設定するため export を実行すると SyntaxError: invalid syntax エラーになる

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, chatgpt

[OpenAI APIを使ってPythonでChatGPT遊びするための最初の三歩くらい](https://dev.classmethod.jp/articles/openai-api-chat-python-first-step/)

上記サイトを参照してChatGPTの実験を行うとしていたのですが、2つ目のコードである `export OPENAI_API_KEY="sk-xxxx"` でエラーが出てしまい、自分なりに試行錯誤をしましたが、先に進むことができませんでした。
解決策を教えて頂けないでしょうか。

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
File "<ipython-input-32-ecb861a59886>", line 1
    export OPENAI_API_KEY="sk-xxxx"
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: `export OPENAI_API_KEY="sk-xxxx"` は Python ではなくシェル(bash や zsh 等)の構文(syntax) です。解決策はウェブ版の ChatGPT で尋ねると良いかと思います。

Answer (score 2):

Jupyter Notebook 内で環境変数を設定するには、マジックコマンドの `%env` または `%set_env` を使います。

**例:**

```
%env ENV=test
```

質問の内容にあわせると、以下のようになりそうです。

```
%env OPENAI_API_KEY=sk-xxxx
```

参考:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/37890898/2322778